# Why is my filtered index not being used for one statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table (an excerpt follows w/o other columns):

```sql
USE [opg-systems-dev]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders]
(
    [SyncChannelEngineOrder] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsSyncing] [bit] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Orders] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] 
    ADD DEFAULT (CONVERT([bit], (0))) FOR [IsSyncing]
GO

-- -----

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Orders_SyncChannelEngineOrder] 
ON [dbo].[Orders] ([SyncChannelEngineOrder] ASC)
WHERE ([SyncChannelEngineOrder] <> (0))
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
      OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Orders_IsSyncing] 
ON [dbo].[Orders] ([IsSyncing] ASC)
WHERE ([IsSyncing] <> (0))
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
      OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I'm trying to use a filtered index here - but it seems when I'm querying that the the index for `SyncChannelEngineOrder` is not being used for some reason.

The setup is supposed to be the same for both columns.

[image]

Comment: Your index isn't covering. They are just on a single column, yet you ask for *all* the columns. You should be have the other columns you likely need in a query the `INCLUDE`. As there's only 1 other column in the table, you definitely should have it in the `INCLUDE`.

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551); even if it is a simple `SELECT` it's likely to attract downvotes.

Comment: @Larnu Hiya - i'm not yet really understanding  why one query would use a index scan and the other wont't while theyre the same in my eyes...

Comment: You have `SELECT *`, but your `INDEX` only has the column `IsSyncing`, for example. An index that doesn't tell you the value of the other columns isn't helpful. If you add the *other* column to the `INCLUDE` you get a seek: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a072823fc42b5dffb7dc172214eeec6c)

Comment: Someone commented something about the row count and the query optimizer (and then removed it) - and he's right SyncChannelEngineOrder returned about 90% of the rows of the table and now that i've set all rows 0 except a few it actually does a index seek rather than a table scan. It seems to be the optimizer being smart.

Comment: Yes, the optimizer is smart and considers how many table reads would likely result from a seek followed by a lookup -- if few rows match the criteria while the table is large (enough), it will switch to seek + lookup. If you "know" this to be the case, you can consider helping it along with a query of the form `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE filteredcol = value)` (if your clustered index is on `ID`). Disclaimer: as always the exact plan you get is not guaranteed and different scenarios should be tested.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yeah the id is that `IsSyncing` is a flag i set when i'm syncing data from my application so in production this will always amound to mayb 1-5% of the total row count of the table so the index makes sense afaik. I was testing this in my dev environment and thus the data was a bit messed up.

Comment: In addition, check the execution plan for the warning "UnmatchedIndexes"

Comment: Note the index seek still requires a key lookup due to the missing columns in the index. Please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @Charlieface hiya i'm a bit uncomfortable sharing the execution plan because it seems to contain a lot of info on the table and my company won't like me sharing such details.

In general the Orders table contains 10 or so columns, mostly decimals with some strings. Then some Fks and a single PK - we use uniqueidentifier for keys.

The index as is still seems to be a lot faster regardless of the key lookup. I could add the missing columns to the index - but that would mean including ALL columumn (because of the ORM in my app - it needs to load the whole entity in some situations)

Comment: You can anonymize it using SentryOne Plan Explorer. I would say at the very least add the filtering columns to the `INCLUDE` otherwise you run into performance issues for updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is requesting all columns with a `select *`. The indexes only contain one column (ignoring the clustered key). To provide the missing column data that is not on the index, the query optimizer is calculating a lower cost to just scan all of the rows in the source table.

If SQL Server chose to use the existing indexes, it would first scan those rows, and then it would perform a bookmark lookup to get the rest of the columns from the table. If there are very few rows in the filtered index, and the table is very large, the SQL Server query optimizer could theoretically calculate a low enough cost to use the filtered index to limit the number of rows. Otherwise, bookmark lookups are expensive on a large number of rows. I am guessing the number of rows in the index is over this threshold.

SQL Server will add the clustered key to a non-clustered index to facilitate the bookmark lookup. If the query were to request only the clustered key and the index filter columns, the indexes would cover the query, and I expect the query optimizer would choose to use the filtered indexes.